# обработка нажатия на экран android

Tags: java, android, экран

Не срабатывает код. В метод onTouch при отладке курсор не попадает вообще. 
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    DrawTest drawView;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {        
             drawView = new DrawTest(this);             
             tv = new TextView(this);
             tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
             setContentView(tv);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);        

       // SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x;
          float y;
          String sDown;
          String sMove;
          String sUp;
          x = event.getX();
          y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            String Down = "Down: " + x + "," + y;
            sMove = ""; sUp = "";
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            sMove = "Move: " + x + "," + y;
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:  
            sMove = "";
            sUp = "Up: " + x + "," + y;
            break;
          }
         // tv.setText(sDown + "\n" + sMove + "\n" + sUp);
          return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы 2 раза подряд делаете `setContentView()`.

Comment: да вы правы - в этом дело, спасибо!